# URL parse vs constructor: path missing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am total beginner in Node.js but I am trying to fix what I thought was a simple issue. I am using the following code example for an AWS Lambda function using Node.js 12 runtime:

```js
function respond(event, context, responseStatus, responseData, physicalResourceId, noEcho) {
    var responseBody = JSON.stringify({
        Status: responseStatus,
        Reason: "See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: " + context.logStreamName,
        PhysicalResourceId: physicalResourceId || context.logStreamName,
        StackId: event.StackId,
        RequestId: event.RequestId,
        LogicalResourceId: event.LogicalResourceId,
        NoEcho: noEcho || false,
        Data: responseData
    });
    var https = require("https");
    var url = require("url");
    var parsedUrl = url.parse(event.ResponseURL);
    var options = {
        hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
        port: 443,
        path: parsedUrl.path,
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "content-type": "",
            "content-length": responseBody.length
        }
    };
    var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
        context.done();
    });
    request.on("error", function(error) {
        console.log("send(..) failed executing https.request(..): " + error);
        context.done();
    });
    request.write(responseBody);
    request.end();
}
```

Full source code can be found here: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-secure-static-site/blob/7f96cdbcfbd7f94c3ab5a4c028b6bafd10744c83/source/witch/witch.js#L70

My IDE gives me a warning that the URL.parse() method is deprecated and so that I should use the URL constructor instead. So the only change I made is replacing:

```
var parsedUrl = url.parse(event.ResponseURL);
```

with

```
var parsedUrl = new url.URL(event.ResponseURL);
```

But when I do that, the options.path field ends up missing. What is even more confusing to me is that if I log the parsedUrl variable (passing it through JSON.stringify()), I can see that when I use url.parse(), I get a simple string in parsedUrl:

```js
"https://cloudformation-custom-resource-response-useast1.s3.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3A123456789012%3Astack/AcmCertificateStack-ABCDEFGHIJKL/00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff%7CCopyCustomResource%7C00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220101T000000Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=7199&X-Amz-Credential=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST%2F20220101%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff"
```

But when using the constructor, I can see in the log an object structure with all the expected fields (protocol, hostname, port, even path):

```js
{
    "protocol": "https:",
    "slashes": true,
    "auth": null,
    "host": "cloudformation-custom-resource-response-useast1.s3.amazonaws.com",
    "port": null,
    "hostname": "cloudformation-custom-resource-response-useast1.s3.amazonaws.com",
    "hash": null,
    "search": "?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220101T000000Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=7199&X-Amz-Credential=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST%2F20220101%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff",
    "query": "XX-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220101T000000Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=7199&X-Amz-Credential=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST%2F20220101%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff",
    "pathname": "/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3A123456789012%3Astack/AcmCertificateStack-ABCDEFGHIJKL/00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff%7CCopyCustomResource%7C00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff",
    "path": "/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3A123456789012%3Astack/AcmCertificateStack-ABCDEFGHIJKL/00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff%7CCopyCustomResource%7C00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220101T000000Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=7199&X-Amz-Credential=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST%2F20220101%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff",
    "href": "https://cloudformation-custom-resource-response-useast1.s3.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3A123456789012%3Astack/AcmCertificateStack-ABCDEFGHIJKL/00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff%7CCopyCustomResource%7C00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220101T000000Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=7199&X-Amz-Credential=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST%2F20220101%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff"
}
```

So if anything the constructor seems to provide a better break down of the URL. I don't why, when I try to copy the parsedUrl.path field to options.path it works when parsedUrl comes from the parse() method but not when it comes from the constructor. The hostname field on the other hand works in both cases.

Any idea what's the issue here?

Comment: What about using `new URL(event.ResponseURL)`?

Comment: What is `options`? Can you share the complete code?

Comment: Following up on the comment of @evolutionxbox, take a look at https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlparseurlstring-parsequerystring-slashesdenotehost, indicating to instead make use of the WHATWG URL API which can be found at the top of the page.  Note that the legacy `.path` attribute is a combination of the `.pathname` and `.search`, so with the new WATWG URL API, it appears as though you will need to construct the path when setting `options.path`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by the OP, the use of the [url.parse](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlparseurlstring-parsequerystring-slashesdenotehost) method is discouraged in favor of the [WATWG URL API](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html).  The legacy [.path](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlobjectpath) attribute returns the combined `pathname` and `search` components.  Although the preferred WATWG URL API does not have the `path` attribute, the value required by `options.path` can be constructed by combining the [.pathname](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlpathname) and [.search](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlsearch) attributes.